# I keep getting the error "object required 'added4'"

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vbscript, compare

I'm trying to create an array of two files and compare the two, but I hit a wall. I keep getting the error "object required 'added4'", I neeed too read two files make them into an array, compare the two and remove lines from the second file that aren't in the first.
I also want to logg the lines I remove.

```
'Reads Approvedshare txt and makes the txt file into an array
        public objFSO 
         Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
         Dim objTextFile 
         Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
            ("TXT PATH") 
         do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
            strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
           public array1 : array1 = trim(strNextLine)
            'wscript.echo "test array : " & array1
           array1 = trim(array1)
            loop


        'Reads current shares txt and also makes that txt into an array
        Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
            ("SECOND TXT PATH")
         do Until objTextFile2.AtEndOfStream
        strNextLine2 = objTextFile2.Readline
       public array2 : array2 = trim(strNextLine2)
        'wscript.echo "test array : " & array2
       array1 = trim(array2)
        loop

'This section is used to compare the two txt files and remove whatever variables that are in both txt files and deleting them.
array2.files
array2.files
   For Each textstream1 In array1
        found = False
    For Each textstream2 In array2
      If textstream1 = textstream2 Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
        found = False
    Next
      If found = False Then
        wscript.echo "This isn't on approve shares text : " &textstream2
     End If 
    Next

'Another section for logging the process, logging the lines that were deleted
```

Comment: please post (short) samples of your input and (desired) output files.

Comment: Input:
test
A
teset1
flexera
flexnet
type
File type
ACT
Act Databases
acttest

Comment: Output would be the same for first txt file but second one would have a couple of lines removed that aren't in the first

Comment: Please don't post that kind of information in comments. Update your question instead. Also, please don't describe the desired output but *show* what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not an answer:**

Given a file X containing the lines:

```
A
B
C
```

a file Y containing:

```
A
B
C
1
2
3
```

and the task to "remove lines from the second file that aren't in the first", so that Y looks like:

```
A
B
C
```

the obvious solution is to copy X over Y - not code, no coding atrocities, no error message.

So what's different in your case?